Norm preserving extensions of a bounded linear operator
I know the Hahn-Banach Theorem is used to extend bounded linear functionals from a subspace to the entire space preserving the norm.
Could you provide a simple, intuitive counterexample to illustrate why extending linear maps preserving the norm is not always possible?
Additionally, under what additional conditions can a bounded linear map defined on a subspace $V \subset W$ be extended to the whole space $W$?
I am looking for both a counterexample and conditions where extension is possible.

take $V=c_0$ (set of sequences converging to $0$), $W=c$ (set of all convergent sequences) and $I:V\to c_0$ be the identity map. There are extensions $W\to c_0$, but any extension has norm $\geq 2$.

If $Y$ is an injective Banach space, then any map $T:V\to Y$ has an extension $T_2:W\to Y$ with the same norm. These are precisely the spaces of the form $C(M)$ where $M$ is a compact Hausdorff extremally disconnected space. Most prominent of such spaces is $\ell^{\infty}$.

what is "trivial extension" you refer to?

@OnurOktay could you please elaborate why the extension will have norm \geq 2. By rivial extesnion I mean defining the functin to be zero for all basis $e_n$ which does not belong to V

this trivial extension will not be bounded in general. in infinite dimensions there's no automatic reason to think that your basis will play nicely with the norm (you could "add coordinates" and decrease the norm for instance). if you're working in a Hilbert space and have a bounded operator defined on a subspace, you can do something that's basically like this by first extending to the closure then extending to $0$ on the orthocomplement of the closure.

@GeorgeCoote Thanks for your comment. Could you provide an explicit example, why trivial extension can be unbounded?

Let $X$ be a normed space and $U$ be a closed subspace without complement, i.e. there is no closed subspace $V\subseteq X$ with $X = U \oplus V$. Consider $T: U \to U, x \mapsto x$ the identity and $\iota: U \hookrightarrow X$ be the inclusion. Then there is no bounded extension of $T$ to $X$ because $p = \iota \circ T: X \to X$ would be a projection ($p^2 = \iota \circ (T \circ \iota) \circ T = \iota \circ \text{id} \circ  T = \iota \circ T = p$) and then $X = \text{Im} \ T \oplus \ker{T} = U \oplus \ker{T}$, a contradiction.
If $X$ is a normed space and $U$ a closed subspace with complement $V$ then every bounded linear map $T: U \to Y$ can be extended by $T \circ p$, where $p: X \to U$ is a projection. If this projection and $T$ is isometric, $T\circ p$ is also isometric.
